# Cakephp 2.0 : Session is false with my custom helper

Tags: session, cakephp, helper

I am facing a problem regarding the Session.
When I had my custom Helper in my controller, the debug($this->Session->read()) give me `false`.
Custom Helper :

```
<?php 

App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

class customFunctionsHelper extends AppHelper { 

public function FormatAddress($address)
{     
    $addr = "";
    if($address['street_name_1'] != "")
        $addr .= $address['street_name_1']."<br />";

    if($address['street_name_2'] != "")
        $addr .= $address['street_name_2']."<br />";

    if($address['street_name_3'] != "")
        $addr .= $address['street_name_3']."<br />";

    if($address['city'] != "")
        $addr .= $address['city'].", ";

    if($address['zipcode'] != "" && $address['state'] != "")
        $addr .= $address['state']." ".$address['zipcode']."<br />";
    else
        $addr .= $address['zipcode']."<br />";

    if($address['country'] != "")
        $addr .= $address['country'];

    if($addr != "")
        return $addr;
    else
        return "<i>Not specified</i>";
}

public function EchoInfo($info)
{
    if($info != "" && $info != 0)
        return $info;
    else
        return "<i>Not specified</i>";
}

} 
?>
```

In my controller, when I had CustomFonctions in the $helpers variable, I have this session problem :

```
class AgendaController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','CustomFunctions');
......
```

Evaluating :

```
debug($this->Session->read());
```

this give me :

```
false
```

Therefore, the $this-Session-setFlash() doesn't work with my custom helper CustomFunctions. 
When I remove the custom helper, it works good...
Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: Does someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `SessionHelper` in `AppHelper` or `customFunctionsHelper` File. If you want to use it.

thanks :)

Comment: Same result with :

    class AppHelper extends Helper {
     public $helpers = array('Session');
    }

Or 

    class CustomFunctionsHelper extends AppHelper { 
        public $helpers = array('Session');
    ...

Answer (score 0):

When I remove the `CustomFunctions` helper in the `$helpers` array. It works and I can access to my custom functions.
It seems that it is not necessary to declare a custom helper in the `$helpers` array...